# OpenCV bitwise operation more than two image

Tags: opencv, bit-manipulation

In OpenCV,
is there any way to bitwise operation more than two image in **one line** code?

for example,

```
result = cv.bitwise_and(source1, source2, source3, source4)
```

something like that.

not like

```
mask1 = cv.bitwise_or(get_mask(0), get_mask(1))
mask2 = cv.bitwise_or(mask1, get_mask(2))
mask = cv.bitwise_or(mask2, get_mask(3))
```

Comment: What do you mean? A logical AND always has two inputs. You can of course chain the result of the first operation to another AND. Depending on the language you use, this is probably done in two lines of code.

Comment: result=mask1 | mask2 | mask3 .... | maskN should work in your case.